# Managing Ruby dependencies for a project

Tags: ruby, maven-2, packaging, bundler

I'm switching to Ruby for a project due to its excellent meta-programming support.

As a Scala guy, I'd use buildr or Maven to manage my project. I could have it generate a skeleton directory structure, add my dependencies, then when I build, the dependencies are downloaded automagically.

How would I use this workflow in Ruby? There seem to be lots of programs that do slightly different things that *sound* like this, and I don't know what their use cases are or what their differences are. It seems like Bundler, Isolate and Jeweler are close, but I don't know which is "best" or most widely-used. I'd like to conform to an idiomatic standard on how to work on larger Ruby projects, just like how Maven-style structures are for Java nowadays.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) is the way to go, at least it's becoming the standard and you can configure it in lots of ways